# Generate function with signature of pointer's type passed to template

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17

I want to create a generator which for each pointer to function will create a `static` function to which the pointer can point to:

```
template <auto &PtrToIsrHandler, auto MemberFunction> struct enable_member_isr_handler
{
    using TypeOfCFunPtr = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(PtrToIsrHandler)>;
    using TypeOfCFunPointed = std::remove_pointer_t<TypeOfCFunPtr>;
    using RetType = std::invoke_result_t<TypeOfCFunPointed>;
    static RetType isr_handler(/* dunno what to put here */)
    {
        return /* call MemberFunction here somehow */;
    }

    enable_member_isr_handler()
    {
        PtrToIsrHandler = isr_handler;
    }

};
```

In the parameter list of the `isr_handler` method I tried to put a tuple by using:

```
template <typename T> struct get_parameters;
template <typename Ret, typename... Args> struct get_parameters<Ret(Args...)>
{
    using args_t = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

But I get then:

```
error: invalid conversion from void (*)(get_parameters<void()>)}’ to ‘void (*)()’
```

How can I make it in such a way that `PtrToIsrHandler` could be a valid pointer to `isr_handler`?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to call a member function you need an instance to call it on. I don't see one anywhere in your example. Other then that I think you are looking for partial template specialization. You can pass on `MemberFunction` and `decltype(MemberFunction)` and use partial specialization to pick up return value and the argument list.

Comment: Might be able to help if you can post the rough syntax for how you would like to _use_ your class. Mainly show how you instantiate enable_member_isr_handler and how you intend to call isr_handler.

Comment: @Barry of course not, this is a bigger problem, but I always split it into smaller problems and almost every problem I try to solve is an XY problem. I'm just experimenting and I try to see whether it can work or not.

Comment: @super the question is really about, how to define a function with the same signature as other function. The main problem I have is how to pick the argument list.

Comment: @K.Koovalsky Seems like you're unfamiliar with the term? See [what is the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/297908)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, one approach to get the argument list is to use partial specialization and forward the type of the passed in member function. The same approach can be used on free functions as well.

```
#include <iostream>

template <auto MemberFunction, class MemberFunctionType>
struct handler_impl;

template <auto MemberFunction, class ReturnType, class ClassType, class... Args>
struct handler_impl<MemberFunction, ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...)> {
    // here you have access to return-type, class-type and args

    static ReturnType call_on_instance(ClassType& obj, Args... args) {
        return (obj.*MemberFunction)(args...);
    }
};

template <auto MemberFunction>
using handler = handler_impl<MemberFunction, decltype(MemberFunction)>;

struct Foo {
    int print(int x) {
        std::cout << x*x << std::endl;
        return x;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    handler<&Foo::print>::call_on_instance(f, 7);
}
```

One thing to keep in mind here is that we are not using perfect forwarding. The easiest approach is to simply make `call_on_instance` a template function, then we don't really need to care about the arguments and return value, we can let the compiler deduce it.

Another option is to use the approach I showed above and use a `static_assert` to make sure the argument list passed in is valid, and thus give a better error message when used in the wrong way.